# I can't use gdb to call a function

Tags: c++, gdb

For the first time I use gdb to call the function `Test()`, it shows `gdborig.exe has stopped working`.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
int a=1;
int Test(){
    return ++a;
}
int main(){
    printf("%d",Test());
return 0;
}
```

Then I reboot the cmd, this time it just exit without any warning.

```
Reading symbols from Test... done.
(gdb) b 7
Breakpoint 1 at Ox401573: file Test.cpp, line 7.
(gdb) r
Starting program: C:\Users\He\Desktop\Test.exe
[New Thread 12420. Ox41ec]
[New Thread 12420. Ox2c68]

Thread 1 hit Breakpoint 1, main () at Test.cpp:7
7           printf("%d", Test()) ;
(gdb) call Test()
```

The gdb version is gdb-8.1

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Did you build the file with debug symbols?

Comment: Which gdb version? 32bit or 64bit executable?

Comment: The gdb version is 64bit.

Comment: The 64bit gdb-8.1 had this bug: [win64: crash inside call_function_by_hand()](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22854). This is very likely the issue you are facing. It was fixed in 8.2.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I install the gdb-9.2 and the problem is fixed.